# Как сделать много анимаций в одном canvas?

Tags: javascript, анимация, canvas, html5-canvas

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться с canvas'ом.

Написал такой скрипт:

```
const ctx = canv.getContext('2d');
const crossImg = new Image();
crossImg.src = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,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';
let xPos = Math.floor(Math.random() * 350);
let yPos = 300;
let a = 22;
let startA = a;
function draw(){

    if(yPos >= canv.height-75){
        startA -= 2;
        a = startA;
    }
    if(startA <= 0 ){
        startA = 0;
        a = 0;
    }
    yPos-=a;
    ctx.clearRect(0 , 0 , canv.width , canv.height);
    ctx.drawImage(crossImg ,xPos, yPos, 75, 75 );

    a -= 0.7;
    requestAnimationFrame(draw);

}
draw();
```

`<canvas width=800px height=600px id="canvas"></canvas>`

Скрипт в принципе работает , но как же сделать , чтобы можно было сделать несколько прыгающих элементов допустим с разной скоростью.

Картинку можно вставлять любую.
Я понимаю , что как-то его нужно запихнуть в массив ,но как не понимаю.

Надеюсь на вашу помощь.

Comment: напишите в этом же методе еще одну отрисовку картинки в другим месте на канве

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Переписал падение, а в целом так можно:

```js
const canv = document.getElementById('canvas');
let w = canv.width = window.innerWidth - 20;
let h = canv.height = window.innerHeight - 20;
let ctx = canv.getContext('2d');

let crossImg = new Image();
crossImg.src = 'https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/35bf0665a75c3439070e28d27dca107b?s=64';

let num = 20;

crossImg.onload = () => {

  arr = [];
  
  for(let i = 0; i < num; i ++){// Задать несколько элементов с разными начальными данными
    arr.push({x : Math.floor(Math.random() * (w - 50)), // Начальное по X
              y : 0, // Начальное положение объекта по высоте
              t : 0, // Начальная скорость (время)
              k : Math.random()*0.5 + 0.1, // Коэффициент прирастания времени (ускорения)
              falling : true, // Состояние падения
              rising : false  // Состояние подъема
              });
  }
  
  function draw(){
     ctx.clearRect(0 , 0 , w , h); // Каждый кадр очищать экран

     // НАЧАЛО ЦИКЛА ПЕРЕБОРА ОБЪЕКТОВ В ОТРИСОВКЕ КАДРА!!!
     arr.forEach(obj => { // Для каждого объекта отрисовывать изображение
       if(obj.falling){
         obj.t += obj.k; // Прирастаем время на шаг 
         obj.y += obj.t*obj.t; // Меняем положение с учетом ускорения
         if(obj.y > h - 52){
           obj.y = h - 52;
           obj.falling = false;
           obj.rising = true;
           //obj.t /= 1.2; Здесь можно корректировать начальную скорость подъема
         }
      }
      
       if(obj.rising){
         obj.t -= obj.k + 0.1; // Дополнительно гасим скорость подъема
         obj.y -= obj.t*obj.t;
         if(obj.t <= 1){
            obj.t = 0;
            obj.rising = false;
            obj.falling = true;
         }
       }
       ctx.drawImage(crossImg ,obj.x, obj.y, 50, 50 ); // Отрисовываем объект
     }) // КОНЕЦ ЦИКЛА!!!


      window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
  }
  draw();
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

**Можно также добавить горизонтальный разброс и остановку по условию отдельных объектов. Когда останавливаются все объекты отменяем анимацию.**

```js
const canv = document.getElementById('canvas');
let w = canv.width = window.innerWidth - 20;
let h = canv.height = window.innerHeight - 20;
let ctx = canv.getContext('2d');

let crossImg = new Image();
crossImg.src = 'https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/35bf0665a75c3439070e28d27dca107b?s=64';

let num = 20;
let animation = null;

crossImg.onload = () => {

  arr = [];
  
  for(let i = 0; i < num; i ++){// Задать несколько элементов с разными начальными данными
    arr.push({x : Math.floor(Math.random() * (w - 50)), // Начальное по X
              y : 0, // Начальное положение объекта по высоте
              t : 0, // Начальная скорость (время)
              k : Math.random()*0.5 + 0.1, // Коэффициент прирастания времени (ускорения)
              falling : true, // Состояние падения
              rising : false,  // Состояние подъема
              left : Math.random() >= 0.5,
              right : !this.left
              });
  }
  
  function draw(){
     ctx.clearRect(0 , 0 , w , h); // Каждый кадр очищать экран

     // НАЧАЛО ЦИКЛА ПЕРЕБОРА ОБЪЕКТОВ В ОТРИСОВКЕ КАДРА!!!
     arr.forEach(obj => { // Для каждого объекта отрисовывать изображение
       if(obj.left){
          obj.x += 1;
          if(obj.x > w - 50){
              obj.left = false;
              obj.right = true;
          }

       } else if (obj.right){
          obj.x -= 1;
          if(obj.x < 0){
              obj.left = true;
              obj.right = false;
          }
       }

       if(obj.falling){
         obj.t += obj.k; // Прирастаем время на шаг 
         obj.y += obj.t*obj.t; // Меняем положение с учетом ускорения
         if(obj.y > h - 52){
           obj.y = h - 52;
           obj.falling = false;
           obj.rising = true;
           //obj.t /= 1.2; Здесь можно корректировать начальную скорость подъема
         }
      }
      
       if(obj.rising){
         obj.t -= obj.k + 0.05; // Дополнительно гасим скорость подъема
         obj.y -= obj.t*obj.t;
         if(obj.t <= 1){
            obj.t = 0;
            obj.rising = false;
            obj.falling = true;
         }
       }
       
       if(obj.y >= h - 52.1){
           obj.falling = false;
           obj.rising = false;
           obj.left = false;
           obj.right = false;
       }
       ctx.drawImage(crossImg ,obj.x, obj.y, 50, 50 ); // Отрисовываем объект
     }) // КОНЕЦ ЦИКЛА!!!
     
     animation = window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
     
     if(arr.every(obj => !obj.falling && !obj.rising && !obj.left && !obj.right)){ // Проверяем двигается ли хоть один объект
         window.cancelAnimationFrame(animation); // Отменяем анимацию и ненужные расчеты в цикле.
         console.log('Анимация отменена!');
     }

  }
  draw();
}
```

```html
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```